# Cant access styles on Nested WPF Style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have Generalized my forms and I have Designed general styles for each types of forms:

```
 <Style TargetType="UserControl" x:Key="ViewForm">
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="18"></Setter>
     <Style.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
             <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IranSans}"/>
             // ...
         </Style>

         <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Right">
             <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IranSans}"/>
         </Style>

         <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Left">
             <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IranSans}"></Setter>
             // ...
         </Style>

         <Style TargetType="Label">
             <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource IranSans}"/>
             // ...
         </Style>
     </Style.Resources>
 </Style>
```

I'm using it in my `UserControls` I expected to be able to use `Left` and `Right` styles for my `TextBlock`s but I have no Access to them. e.g :

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource Right}">Email :</TextBlock>
```

*** everything are ok with those Styles who has no `x:Key="SomeKey..."`

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User control "Resources" and user control "Style Resources" are two different things. User control's nested controls like textbox, labels will have access to "Resources" NOT to "Style Resources".

So correct way to do this is -

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
  <!-- Place all styles that you want to put over child controls -->
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Style>
  <Style>
        <Style.Resources>
             <!-- Place all styles that you want to use within this style -->
        </Style.Resources>
   </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont want put all of the styles in to each page. after some tries, I have put these styles in a resourceDictionary and i added them into my usercontrol through MergedDictionaries. 
Can we set a UserControl's Resource through a Style ? If it possible, i want to add those styles into UserControl's style

Comment: you can place all child control styles in global resourceDictionary and access it from there instead of keeping it inside an individual user control file. Only thing child styles should not be placed under another type <style> resources.

Comment: So we can't set the Control's Style in such a nested way that we have in CSS ?
(in CSS we have such a Selector for our style `.Class1 .Class2 {.....}` which is a nested styling)

Comment: @RezaNoei I don't think, WPF supports such thing out of box.